# Craycc equivalent for "mcmodel"

Tags: cc, relocation, cray

I am trying to compile a C code under craycc.  Compilation fails with the error "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32".  Under Intel or GNU I can get past this error with the "mcmodel" flag.  But craycc does not recognize this flag.  Does anyone know of an equivalent flag/approach under craycc?  I looked in the craycc man page, but couldn't find any discussion of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is ever interested, the flag `-h pic` gets the Cray compiler past the problem and produces a running executable.  I don't know how exact the equivalence is between this flag and the `-mcmodel=medium` flag, but that's what was needed to solve this particular problem.